# How do we refresh /.info/serverTimeOffset on device time change?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using /.info/serverTimeOffset to get the approximate server time from firebase.

```
Long clockSkew = null;
...
void registerForClockSkew() {
  DatabaseReference offsetRef = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
  offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
      clockSkew = (long) offset;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
      clockSkew = null;
    }
  });
}
```

However as mentioned here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/363 - the offset does not refresh when there is a device-time-change. I have tried to close and reconnect firebase instance to refresh the skew value but it does not seem to be working. In my code I simply put the following when there is device time change -

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
```

but this does not trigger the value-event-listener callback. What am I missing here? Is it because goOffline and goOnline are consecutive statements, it is not having any effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to handle the situation that I have found is to keep the skew w.r.t `elapsedRealtime` which keeps constant in case of device time change.

```
long clockSkewWRTELapsed
....
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
      clockSkewWRTELapsed = ((long) offset) + System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealTime();
    }
```

Whenever needed, one can get the server-time by adding elapsedRealTime to the clockSkewWRTElapsed time.

Comment: yeah, use SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() can fix the case device time change. Thanks